# Mongoose get array of Date with Values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i wanna enter a startDate and a endDate to my Mongoose Aggregation to get the registered Users foreach day between the range. I know i could user the normal count function but i thinkt its better to use the aggregations for it what do you think?

```
var startDate = 2016-01-05;
var endDate = 2016-01-07;
history : [
    ['2016-01-05', 23], // Day 1 = 23 Users
    ['2016-01-06', 34], // Day 2 = 34 Users
    ['2016-01-07', 43]  // Day 3 = 43 Users
];
```

so i'm searching for something like

`User.aggregate(
                    [
                        {
                            "$group": {
                                "created": {
                                    $gte: startDate,
                                    $lt: endDate
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ], function (err, users) {
                        history.push(users);
                    }
                );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation indeed would be the ideal solution but how it generates the result is different from your expected output, depending on your application needs (I presume most probably you want to use this data
to display in a graph).

You could approach this in a couple of ways. Not the best solution since it depends on how your data is structured, i.e. it assumes the `created` date field in your `users` collection follows a time series (a users is created per day) and is a proper mongo date, but will at least get you going.

Let's consider the aggregation pipeline first. Since you want to produce a list of user counts for each day within a specified data range, you could construct
your pipeline in such a way that after the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline step, use the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_group)** operator to create as the group key a string representation of the `created` date field using the **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#exp._S_dateToString)** operator, which can be used to group by a day in the `"YYYY-MM-DD"` format. Then get the count of each accumulated documents using the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)**
operator:

```
var startDate = new Date("2016-01-05");
var endDate = new Date("2016-01-08");

var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "created": {
                "$gte": startDate,
                "$lt": endDate
            }
        }
    },      
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "yearMonthDay": { 
                    "$dateToString": { 
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                        "date": "$created" 
                    } 
                }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
];
```

You can then run the aggregation pipeline, manipulate the result to get the final array in the desired format:

```
User.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, users){
    if (err) {/* handle error */ }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));
    var data = users.map(function (u){  return [u._id.yearMonthDay, u.count]; });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
});
```

Comment: All work fine with your solution big thanks for that. There are just two more Question i have. Question1: How could i fill Days where UserValue is 0 with 0 instead of ignore this days? Question 2: How i could handle if startDate and endDate are the same day the $group statement to return every hour of the day and give me the value of each hour ?